# Why is python regex search not detecting all numbers using asterisks * when + does?

Tags: python, regex

just wondering why the use of asterisks does not detect the numbers in this example?

```
example = "something_119086"
re.search('\d*', example).group()
''
```

It works for numbers at the beginning of a string, but "search" is supposed to scan the entire string for 0 or more occurences.

However using + instead of * works, which searches for 1 or more occurrences.

Comment: Did any of the answers below resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk searches for 0 or more occurrences of the character(-set). It finds 0 occurrences in the character `s` and as `re.search` only reports one match you get `''`. You can see this by typing:

```
re.findall(r'\d*', example)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[8]: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '119086', '']
```

So yes, the asterisk detects the number (`\d*`), but also everything else.

EDIT: Remember to use raw strings (prefix with `r`) for regular expressions in order to prevent unwelcome surprises

Comment: oh yes, you're definitely right; will update

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match
>   object.

The asterisk means *0 or more*. It successfully matches zero numbers at the very start of the string and returns that.